# Ruby-on-rails evaluation of mathementical expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macros

In `Ruby-on-rails`, I am receiving input from a call to a `XL macro`(currently hard coded), which places a mathematical expression in the spreadsheet.  If I call the macro I will receive a worksheet with an expression like this in one of the cells

```
x + ( 3 / 12)
```

In the R-O-R application I wish to take this expression and evaluate for different values of `x`.

```
row.each do |row|
   y = row
end
```

I want to find the value of `y` for say example `x = 2` ? Should I receive this expression as a literal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` and `gsub` will get you most of the way there.  Fire up `irb`:

```
(533)⚡️ irb
2.1.2 :001 > exp = 'x + (3 / 12)'
 => "x + (3 / 12)" 
2.1.2 :002 > eval(exp.gsub(/x/, '25'))
 => 25 
2.1.2 :003 > exp = 'x + (4.0 / 25.0) + 4'
 => "x + (4.0 / 25.0) + 4" 
2.1.2 :004 > eval(exp.gsub(/x/, '25'))
 => 29.16
```

Notice the result of command `002`.  Ruby is assuming the `3 / 12` is integer math, so the result will be an integer, which is `0` in this case.  In `003` floating point math occurs because the numbers are decimals.  This aspect may be an issue you need to tackle more creatively, or just make sure your expressions conform to the type of math you need to occur.

*Be aware of the security concerns with `eval`, you're executing Ruby code in there, so mean people may put mean things in there to try and execute it.*

Comment: 3/12 - more craatively - what do I look at ?

Comment: NO! Please do not eval things off the network. Even if this app is not high security, this can compromise the whole computer it's running on if anyone manages to send it a request. If you are qualified to decide this is OK to do in a given situation, you are most likely not reading this question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: They asked how to do something, I answered with a warning, my conscious is clear. :)  I italicized it for emphasis too!

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function to do this securely. You need a math parser and evaluator. You can write one yourself or you could use an existing one like Dentaku.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a one line function, as following:

```
def foo(x) x + (3 / 12) end
```

Now you can use this to calculate any value of `x`, for `x = 2`, you can do: `foo(2)` or `foo 2`.

Comment: The sactual expression will be a log-normal expression which I have to provide three sample values to and the macro determines returns the log-normal expression fitting the threee provided points.